# Tensorflow: Error when operate on tensor of string

Tags: python, string, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-serving

I am using TensorFlow Serving. As an input, I have a tensor of string. First I want to do some transformations with the input tensor and then I want to do the operations of the model. My code looks like this:

```
split_value = person_mail.split("@")

placeholder_person_mail= 'person_mail'    
person_mail = tf.placeholder(tf.string, 1, name=placeholder_person_mail)

print("Test {}".format(sess.run(split_value, feed_dict={clients_name:["fran@gmail.com"])))
```

The output should be: `["fran", "gmail.com"]`

But I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-7422666405996158092.py", line 367, in 
>        raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
>        Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-7422666405996158092.py", line 355, in 
>        exec(code, _zcUserQueryNameSpace)
>        File "", line 8, in 
>        AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'split'